# Android Studio does not detect .aidl files

Tags: android-studio, aidl

I have found a sample from the Internet (https://github.com/manishkpr/Android-AIDL-Example) and ran on Android Studio and it worked fine.

But now when I am trying to recreate the project, the Android Studio fails to recognize the 
.aidl file no matter where I place it.
Can anybody tell me what is the right location to place .aidl files in Android Studio?

p.s. I have added the below code to build.gradle and place the .aidl file in the java directory, but failed to get it work.

```
sourceSets {
main {
    aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The below link solved my issue.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56160

Answer (score 16):

In my case `Clean` and `Rebuild` project solved my problem.
Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 6):

The default Android project sourceSet has a definition that looks for .aidl files under "src/main/aidl".  Moving my aidl files there solved the problem.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56328

Comment: This link helped me because I was not seeing the gen folder showing aidl being generated by the build. The link (#2) mentions that it can also appear in build/generated/source/aidl (their path was writen different, but same result).

Comment: It seems this isn't true for gradle 4.1 anymore. I never even had a sourceSets declaration in my build.gradle before 4.1. I also needed to give it the path to manifest, source and res as it didn't find NOTHING after the update.
I am totally convinced they just hate app-devs.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your build.gradle.kts:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures.aidl = true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AIDL files need to be generated, that's why sometimes when you need to declare a class that is located in an AIDL file, you first have to build these AIDL files before Android Studio can resolve their content.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

or

```
gradle assemble
```

You can also run the task (assemble) under gradle -> build -> assemble

Answer (score 0):

In new Android Studio Giraffe, found solution in this way-

1. Add this in build.gradle first
   buildFeatures {
   aidl true
   }
2. Right click on app > New > Aidl > Aidl file
   Now add the aidl file name, and enter
   aidl folder, with the current package name under which the given name .aidl file, all will be created.